# Unwrapping all objects inside of the same UV space

Tags: modeling, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

This is kind of a beginner question, so I apologize upfront.

Imagine the interior of a room made with Blender. Let's say, a dining room.

Inside of it, we have obviously the walls, floor and ceiling. But we do also have more objects inside, like a television. A sofa. A chimney. Some paintings on the walls. An antique ceiling lamp. You get the point.

[image: dining-room]

I'm just starting out my journey on UV Unwrapping, oriented to game development. My question is the following: should I UV Unwrap all things (i.e. walls, floor, ceiling, chimney, TV, sofas, paintings, lamp, tables, chairs, ...) into the same UV space? What are best practices here that I should follow?

Thank you, and again, I apologize for such a beginner question.

Answer (score 1):

well, after my short experience with blender i do believe UV unwrapping every single object would allow for more customisation.

You would be able to make better use of Textures and Maps (Normal, specular, etc.) while keeping a reasonable amount of control.

Furthermore, applying one UV Map to the whole room would certainly be messy. You would lose sight of what's what very quickly.

BTW I'm a beginner myself, so pls don't hate.

EDIT: Don't Game Engines also differentiate between objects (except maybe for complete static rooms etc.) ?

Comment: Yes, game engines do differentiate between the different objects inside of a .blend file. Thanks for the answer