# Workflow question and advice [uv-mapping, modular or singular build?]

Tags: modeling, export

[image]Now that i have just recently been able to wrap my  head around uv-mapping i don't see it to be sensible to build a complete structure like this one [inside & out] and then try to un-wrap it. So would it be better to build in pieces un-wrapping as you go? and piece it together when complete, then import?. How would you pros go about building a enter-able structure such as this stave church i'm building. It's the church from netflix's show DARK. A must see BTW.

Comment: It is more manageable to unwrap the pieces as you make them.

Comment: It depends on a lot on your workflow, how close are you going to be to the object when rendered ? do you want to use it in a cinematic animation or realtime in a video game ? etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you ask mainly what is answered on this post which is relevant because it describes when you need different textures and uvs :

[Texturing each object separately VS all in the same texture file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64511/texturing-each-object-separately-vs-all-in-the-same-texture-file)

generally there is no any rule but it is a common practice to keep things separated depending again on their final usage (gaming, archviz, animation etc), it is more a combination of scale, complexity and purpose.